# Who is Meta-man?

Tags: discussion, users, moderators

On [V'Dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam), the Mi Yodeya chat site, one can often find a user named "Meta-Man" sharing interesting meta-posts about site governence or pointing out interesting discussions, but I cannot tell who or what Meta-Man is. It could be a specific moderator with a different name on Mi Yodeya Meta. It could be an avatar used by various moderators to post interesting things. It does not seem to be a standard user profile since it is not listed as a user on the main Mi Yodeya users list or the Meta users list.

Comment: The Meta-Man (automatically?) posted this question about himself on V'Dibarta Bam. Cool!

Answer (score 6):

He likes to help out but very much prefers to remain anonymous.

<sub>If you are over 40 years old and have mastered all revealed parts of Torah, you can view the below information:</sub>

> <sub>https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123580</sub>